# Azure Devops nuget restore unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget

I have a dotnet web api project with EF. When I try to configure build and run the **Nuget Restore** step fails with below errors

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in E:\TFS_Agents2017\...\s\ABC.Employees\ABC.Employees.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
Errors in E:\TFS_Agents2017\....\s\EmployeesEF\EmployeesEF.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
Errors in E:\TFS_Agents2017\...\s\UnitTests\abcUnitTests.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
Errors in E:\TFS_Agents2017\...\s\askldf\asdfasdf.UnitTests.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.)
Packages failed to restore
```

Am I missing anything, do I need to add any other steps ?

Comment: We recently had an issue with this with some packages with some of our builds? Is it all packages that are failing or just certain ones? How do you have to restore configured in your build? Is it a separate restore step, or is it the deprecated restore option on the build step?

Comment: From the steps I see below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops   Its a separate restore step that i used by adding task.    Only the above mentioned errors are shown

Comment: with the separate restore step, what version of that step are you using?

Comment: Task Version 2.* I also tried to add step dot net sdk to install .net core 3.1.0 as my project is dependent on it, but it also fails because of proxy

Comment: Sounds like it is a different scenario than what we faced then. (with ours it was builds suddenly started failing to restore certain packages no matter which nuget repo those particular packages were sourced from, updating the build to use the separate restore step v2.* resolved it. The new step references a newer version of nuget. Still no idea why the old one stopped working though) The other difference is our projects were .net framework not core.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, please check it. Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot see the .NET Core SDK version 3.1.0 in the [agent info](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-core-sdk).
Please run the cmd `dotnet –info` to check your local .NET Core SDK version and Runtime version, then open the build definition and add the task [.NET Core SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) and [.NET Core restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) to restore the package.
[image]